# How to use memorization in recursion to solve 0-1 Knapsack problem without Runtime Error for larger inputs in c ++?

Tags: c++11, recursion, knapsack-problem

Iam doing this 0-1 knapsack problem in GFG practice portal. For small inputs the code is running fine! .For bigger inputs I am getting an "Time Limit Exceeded" error. I am new to DP concept can someone explain what is my mistake  .I have used (recursion +memorization).

Link to the problem:https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/0-1-knapsack-problem0945/1#

Here is the code :

```
int a[10005][10005]; // I have declared this globally.

int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n) 
{ 
     memset(a,-1,sizeof(a));

     if (n == 0 || W == 0)
     {
     return 0;
     }

     if(a[n][W]!=-1)
     {
     return a[n][W];
     }

     if (wt[n - 1] > W)
     {
     a[n][W]=knapSack(W, wt, val, n - 1);  
     return a[n][W];
    }

    if(wt[n - 1] <= W)
    {
    a[n][W]= max(val[n - 1]+ knapSack(W - wt[n - 1],wt, val, n - 1),knapSack(W, wt, val, n - 1));
    return a[n][W];
    }
}
```

For smaller Input's:

For Input:

3   // n=no.of inputs

4    //W capacity of the bag

1 2 3   //val[ ]

4 5 1    //wt[ ]

your output is:
3

For larger Input's:

"Time Limit Exceeded"

Comment: The call to `memset()` is probably the culprit. It should be done outside `knapSack()`.

Comment: May I ask where do those `10005` magic numbers come from? The limits mentioned in the linked problem statement are all `1000`.

Comment: @Bob__ yes you are right the limit is 1000. I thought of taking '5' extra space i.e 1000+5=1005 for safety purpose  to avoid boundary clash .  But because of my bad math I made it 10005 instead of 1005.But that is not a concern because the extra space is not which is making the program to crash .If that is the case I would get an memory limit error.

Answer (score 0):

`memset(a,-1,sizeof(a));`
`memset` takes an argument in *bytes*, so you cleared 1/4 of the array (depends on your int size).  Fortunately the value -1 becomes the byte 0xff which, when placed in each of the bytes of the `int`, represent -1 again.  The value -1 is special in that regard, along with 0.  Generally, it's better to use `std::fill`.  (although that's complicated by the use of a two-dimensional array)

OK, you have recursive calls like:
`a[n][W]=knapSack(W, wt, val, n - 1);`

and presumably you keep needing the *same* ones that you already calculated.

You need to keep a database of all the ones you already computed.  A simple way to do that is to make a `std::map` and the key is a structure containing the four values, and the result as the value.  Wrap your real function (renamed) with a new function that first checks the database, and if not already present, calls the real function, stores the result in the database, and then returns.

---

Ah, you seem to already be implementing memoization via your global arrays... As [Bob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4944425/bob) pointed out in a comment, the `memset` is *inside* the recursive function, so each call wipes out the saved values.

Comment: Well, no, that's [not the problem](https://godbolt.org/z/rE7bfjGrK) with that call to `memset`. That array should just be initialized outside the function.